# How to change item state on FlatList without affecting other items on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image]

I like to increase the count of Item 1 without changing the count of Item 2 and Item 3. How do I do that in React Native? I am a beginner.

Here is my code: (Never mind the AppText and AppButton component those are my own)

```
const items = [
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2 },
        { id: 3 }
    ]

    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)

    return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={items}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (

                        <View style={styles.item}>

                            <AppText style={styles.number}>Item {item.id} |</AppText>

                            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                                <AppButton title={"-"} type={"contained"} style={styles.button} onPress={() => setQuantity(quantity - 1)} />
                            </View>

                            <AppText style={styles.number}>{quantity}</AppText>

                            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                                <AppButton title={"+"} type={"contained"} style={styles.button} onPress={() => setQuantity(quantity + 1)} />
                            </View>

                        </View>

                    )}
                />
            </View>
```

Comment: state should be object for this case {id1:0,id2:0...} , increment the count for particular id on the state , for eg. if you want to increase the count for id1....setState(...state,id:state.id+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's better to add a key-value in `items` object for `quantity` and
  handle that `items` state only (Don't depend on other state if we can handle the `data` that passed to `FlatList`).
- Also it's always better to maintain good code formatting for
  readability like don't handle functions directly in `onPress` instead
  create a separate function to handle that

Try below code

```
const initialItems = [
     { id: 1, quantity:0 },
     { id: 2, quantity:0 },
     { id: 3, quantity:0 }
]

const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems)

const updateQuantity = (index, value) => {
   if(value < 0) return;
   const tempItems = [...items];
   tempItems[index].quantity = value
   setItems(tempItems)
}

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={items}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <AppText style={styles.number}>Item {item.id} |</AppText>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <AppButton title={"-"} type={"contained"} style={styles.button} onPress={() => updateQuantity(index, item.quantity - 1)} />
          </View>
          <AppText style={styles.number}>{item.quantity}</AppText>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <AppButton title={"+"} type={"contained"} style={styles.button} onPress={() => updateQuantity(index, item.quantity + 1)} />
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    />
  </View>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this solved my problem. But only I question and ive been trying to figure it out. How do I prevent the quantity from reaching 0 if pressed on the decrease button? Thank you

Comment: I already put a condition inside `updateQuantity` function `if(value < 0) return;`. This will prevent after reaching zero. If you want minimum value `1` then update that condition like this `if(value < 1) return;`

Answer (score 1):

Need to create a useState object to map the values

```
const items = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
]

const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState({1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0})


<View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={items }
                renderItem={({ item }) => (

                    <View style={styles.item}>

                        <AppText style={styles.number}>Item {item.id} |</AppText>

                        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                            <AppButton title={"-"} type={"contained"} style={styles.button} onPress={() => setQuantity((state) => ({...state,{[item.id] : state[item.id] - 1} })} />
                        </View>

                        <AppText style={styles.number}>{quantity[item.id] || 0}</AppText>

                        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                            <AppButton title={"+"} type={"contained"} style={styles.button} onPress={() => setQuantity((state) => ({...state,{[item.id] : state[item.id] + 1} })} />
                        </View>

                    </View>

                )}
            />
        </View>
```